# How to set different percentages for Mobile & Tablets

Tags: android, android-layout, android-percent-layout

I am currently using **android.support.percent API**

My sample code

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
 <TextView
     android:text="Completed"
     app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
     app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
     app:layout_marginTopPercent="15%"
     app:layout_marginLeftPercent="15%"/>
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout/>
```

**My problem:**

Percent relative layout fit correctly in Tablets... But some views are display very small in mobile phone.

So I want to increase the percentage for phone only.. not tablets.

**My question:**

How to set different percentage for phones & tablet using percent relative layout.(like different dimensions)

app:layout_heightPercent="40%" // fit for tablet 
But I want to increase to 50% for phone..

Comment: as usual ... store values in size dependend resources

Comment: @Selvin its tricky.. its %.. not string or DP.. So I am confused.

Comment: it's `fraction`

Comment: thanks.. looks like may be my problem solved

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing XML resource type for PercentRelativeLayout Percentage value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32397379/missing-xml-resource-type-for-percentrelativelayout-percentage-value)

Comment: @Selvin I don`t know about fraction.. I searched in google & SO. but not found above link. sorry for duplicate qtn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use smallest width dimens

[image]

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
 <TextView
     android:text="Completed"
     app:layout_widthPercent="@fraction/width"
     app:layout_heightPercent="@fraction/height"
     app:layout_marginTopPercent="@fraction/margin_top"
     app:layout_marginLeftPercent="@fraction/margin_left"/>
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout/>
```

and in dimens:

dimens.xml

```
<fraction name="width">40%</fraction>
    <fraction name="height">40%</fraction>
    <fraction name="margin_top">15%</fraction>
    <fraction name="margin_left">15%</fraction>
```

and dimens.xml (sw 600dp)

```
<fraction name="width">40%</fraction>
    <fraction name="height">50%</fraction>
    <fraction name="margin_top">15%</fraction>
    <fraction name="margin_left">15%</fraction>
```

you can see more detail for design screen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36820746/how-to-design-any-screen-size-and-density-in-androidmulti-screen-for-mobiles/36821546#36821546)

Comment: sorry not working.. it shows error - (fraction not allowed) when I compiling

Comment: @RanjithKumar sorry i had a mistake. i did edit it. it should be work now.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at my answer right here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39571409/6644403

Tablet size is large so use ur current layout with percentage with the qualifier "Large" or "X Large" and create another one with no qualifier or "Normal" qualifier for mobile, where you can change size of your view.

Comment: I know the different dimensions folder structure..  I am asking how to store the percentage value

Comment: How to set different percentage for phones & tablet using percent relative layout.(like different dimensions)

app:layout_heightPercent="40%" // fit for tablet But I want to increase to 50% for phone..

Your question isnt about storing percentage values or am i missunderstanding ?

Answer (score 0):

For a workaround you can use different layout folders for different screens. For phone **layout** folder and for tablet **layout-large**.

**screen.xml** for **layout** folder

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
 <TextView
     android:text="Completed"
     app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
     app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
     app:layout_marginTopPercent="15%"
     app:layout_marginLeftPercent="15%"/>
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout/>
```

**screen.xml** for **layout-large** folder

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
 <TextView
     android:text="Completed"
     app:layout_widthPercent="80%"
     app:layout_heightPercent="80%"
     app:layout_marginTopPercent="30%"
     app:layout_marginLeftPercent="30%"/>
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout/>
```